# Is it safe to add a 3rd partition to my hard drive so I can format Windows while saving important data?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, format

Is it safe to add a 3rd partition so I have 3:

1. system reserve
2. C:windows
3. Important data

Then move all important files to the 3rd partition, then re-install Windows, then proceed to move those files back? I have to format my PC but I have 100 GB of files I can’t lose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure which files you want to keep and make sure they are on the right partition yes, that will work, but you have to be careful that all the files you need to keep get stored on the important files partition.  Many Windows programs are poorly written and assume that you only have one hard drive, that they can store files wherever they want (most older programs), or that you don't need access to the files directly, so they shouldn't be with all the other documents that you would normally want to keep (database files, or mail stores, for example).

The only way to know for sure with the programs you use is to actually try it out--which requires either a backup of the windows partition just in case there is an issue, or being OK with losing some files.

Comment: i tried it, it worked